# What's up with the Twizzlers aroma?

Tags: aging, aroma, barleywine

So I tried my first barleywine last night, and went with one that was recommended several places: [Blithering Idiot](http://www.weyerbacher.com/beers/year-round/blithering-idiot). Although not obvious at first, after a few minutes this beer started smelling more and more like Twizzlers. To the point where I'm pretty sure whatever they make Twizzlers out of is present in this beer in a *significant* amount.

So my question is sort of 3-fold: what exactly is causing this aroma, is it an intentional quality (if anyone happens to know), and will it start to go away if I lay it down for a while?

Comment: Can you add more details? What fermentation temperature? What yeast? How old is the barley wine? How did you store it?

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. Blithering Idiot is a brand of barleywine. I (obviously) don't have insider information on that sort of thing. I was wondering if anyone had brewed anything with that sort of flavor/aroma and what they had done to make it that way.

Comment: Twizzlers come in various flavours. Did "Blithering Idiot" exhibit all those flavours or (for example) just liquorice or strawberry?

Comment: Just the most popular one. I think that one is cherry, but it's never tasted like anything in particular to me, just Twizzlers.

Comment: So, to clarify, you did not brew a blithering idiot clone, you just drank one that you bought?

Comment: Correct. I'm curious about the brewing conditions that would create this aroma and whether it will decrease with age

Answer (score 1):

It can be hard to help with perceived flavors here due to obvious limitations.

If you can use this tool to best describe it, then we can help with solutions.

http://www.beerflavorwheel.com

Usually barley wines are boiled a very long time to achieve the OG. This will also give the beer the effects of carmeling the wort in the boil producing a wide array of maliard notes. Also being a hoppy beer the style is open to all of those possible flavors and aromas.